# Unclear blit_into() error

Tags: python, pyglet

When i'm calling blit_into(), like this:

```
something.blit_into(some_texture, x, y, 0)
```

I get this error:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Why it happens?

Comment: You'll have to provide your code. SO is not a forum of psychics, so we don't know where in your code this occurs. At a quick glance, however, it seems that whatever `y` is, it is the wrong type. Check out what `type(y)` is and whether that `type` is appropriate for the `blit_into` function.

Comment: So, it turned out that blit_into() doesn't work if "some_texture" is bigger than "something", and my resizement of "some_texture" using texture.width/height parameters won't work since "some_texture" has to be ImageData, not TextureRegion. Gotta find a way to resize it correctly.